# how do you create dynamic templates using props in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state that contains an array and then the data from the state I will throw to the child component, from the child component I have a dynamic card so I throw the data again to the card component, how do I use the card component in other components? I try to use components cards in other components such as the home component, but the props are undefined

this.is my event component

```
class Events extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data:[
        {id:1, title:'Kelebihan Ford Everest 1', type:'Berita 1', role:'Administrator 1', img:require("../../assets/img/event-1.jpg"), date:new Date()},
        {id:2, title:'Kelebihan Ford Everest 2', type:'Berita 2', role:'Administrator 2', img:require("../../assets/img/event-1.jpg"), date:new Date()},
        {id:3, title:'Kelebihan Ford Everest 3', type:'Berita 3', role:'Administrator 3', img:require("../../assets/img/event-1.jpg"), date:new Date()},
      ],
      loading:true,
      title:'page event'
    }
  }

render() {
    const {data,loading} = this.state;

    if(loading){
      return (
        <p>loading...</p>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <PageHeader title={this.state.title} />
        <EventChild data={data} />
      </div>     
    );
  }
}
```

and this is component eventChild

```
class EventChild extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.data.map(data => {
          return (
            <>
              <NewsCards id={data.id} type={data.type} title={data.title} role={data.role} img={data.img} />
              {this.props.children}
            </>
          )
        })}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is my card template 
so far there is still no problem, if I use a card component in the home component I get a problem, this.props.data is undefined, how do I if I want to use a card component that has data from the event component then I use it in the home component?

```
class NewsCards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <Link to="/news-detail">
          <div className="card" key={this.props.id}>
            <img className="card-img-top img-card-rounded" src={this.props.img} alt="Card image cap" />
            <div className="card-body">
              <p className="card-text mb-1"><span className="badge badge-pill badge-warning mr-1">{this.props.type}</span> <small>{this.props.date} - {this.props.role}</small></p>
              <a className="text-link" href="#"><h5 className="card-title">{this.props.title}</h5></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my component home

```
class Home extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <NewsCards {...this.props.data} />
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in CodeSandBox? It will be easier to debug for us.

Comment: oke arshad wait

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have a problem with the "data" **prop** in the home component are you sure that you passed this **prop** to the Home component

Comment: how do I get the data props? I've tried it several times but the results are undefined,
I just learned react about 1 mounth ago

Comment: When you use the **Home** component pass the data **<Home data={dataObject} />**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a fundamental mistake here. In EventChild component, you are passing every property separately to NewsCards. While in Home Component, you are passing a whole object. Using props.data will always lead to undefined because there's no such props passed. Try consoling the props in NewsCard when you initialize it in Home Component.

Comment: I tried calling this.props.data in the NewsCard component, but the props was undefined

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing default state and use componentDidMount lifecycle